# Android Virtual Device in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I try to run my project in Android Virtual Device (i.e., emulator) from Android Studio, I run into a problem: `Gradle Execution Failed`.

What is this problem? Before encountering this error, I have created an AVD.

This is the error window:

[image: Gradle error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting Gradle errors, it means your project is not building successfully.  You have to solve that before you get to running the AVD.  Please look in the Event Log and Gradle Console areas in the lower part of your Android Studio window and report back what it says.

If the project builds, you will see a dialog that allows you to choose a target (AVD or real device).

If you suspect something is wrong with your AVD or real device setup, I recommend creating the empty "Hello World" app and making sure it builds, installs and runs on your AVD.